# Limitation in QModbusTcpClient's data size

Tags: c++, windows, qt5, modbus-tcp

**The story behind:** Using a [`QModbusTcpClient`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmodbustcpclient.html) I am trying to read the content from a device connected to a `Modbus/TCP` network. For that purpose I have written a Windows program (tested on 7 and 10) in Qt C++ (Qt version 5.7.0) which essentially calls [`QModbusClient::sendReadRequest`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmodbusclient.html#sendReadRequest) with [`QModbusDataUnit::QModbusDataUnit(RegisterType type, int address, quint16 size)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmodbusdataunit.html#QModbusDataUnit-2) as a parameter, where *type* is `HoldingRegisters`, *address* equals to `1000` (could be another address, it is not important for this particular issue) and *size* is the length of the desired data to be read from the device.

**The issue:** Everything works well when `size` is less or equal to `63` registers. Every attempt to go beyond this value results in an error, which depends on the device I am testing the program with, but generally says invalid request.

**Tests:**

1. I have tested this with several real devices and with a [`Modbus/TCP`
   simulator](http://www.plcsimulator.org/) obtaining the same results, i.e. `size` <= `63` -> okay; `size` >
   `63` -> error
2. [`Modpoll`](http://www.modbusdriver.com/modpoll.html) from another side allows me to read a data chunk from the same devices and simulator with a `size` greater than `63` registers

**Some research:** [Here](http://modbus.control.com/thread/1249550734) it is stated, that there is indeed a limitation, but it is 256 bytes, which equals to 128 16-bit registers, in other words - way above the limit of my read attempts.

**My suspicion:** It appears that `QModbusTcpClient` does not allow reading more than a `63` registers.

**Question:** Have anyone experienced such an issue using `QModbusTcpClient` and is there a way to overcome this limitation, apart from reading the data on two passes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the solution, which worked in my case is to take the matter in my hands and write my own class to communicate with the Modbus devices. The class inherits from `QObject`, so the signal-slot system is still at disposal, however the actual functionality is based around the `winsock2.h`. [Here](http://paginas.fe.up.pt/~pfs/recursos/plcs/modbus/sources.html) is a sample program, which does the job for what I need. Another useful sources I have stumbled upon are [this book](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/print/bgnet_A4_2.pdf), the [example program](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms740149(v=vs.85).aspx) from the winsocket 2 reference and of course the [Modbus specification](http://modbus.org/docs/Modbus_Messaging_Implementation_Guide_V1_0b.pdf). It turned out, that it is not so difficult and with a little bit of help from the sources I've mentioned I was able to solve the problem I've had.